# JSP useBean: Undefined type error

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jetty

I have configured Jetty at my Project (Eclipse Neon).

I've created `index.jsp` under `WebContent` folder, and my Java class is under `WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/foo`. The class name is `FooClass.java`.

At `index.jsp`, I've set this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="R1" class="foo.FooClass"/>
```

Eclipse is alerting me on the useBean tag saying `foo.FooClass` is an undefined type. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless `WebContent/WEB-INF/classes` is listed on the project's Java Build Path as a **Class Folder** or a **Source Folder**, and not just an output folder that you've added the class file to yourself, it won't be found by anything the project attempts to compile or validate.

Comment: Thanks, dude! I was able to solve this issue by replacing my Java classes files to the correct path. Thank you!